# Drinking and Driving

Tags: united-states, driving, california

In the state of California, what is the limit of alcohol allowed in bloodstream to be prosecuted under drinking and driving case?

And what are the procedures used for intoxication testing (other than breathalyzer) while being pulled over?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the California Vehicle Code, the thresholds for driving under the influence are:

- 0.04% BAC if [driving a commercial vehicle](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=23152.)
- 0.01% BAC if [under a DUI probation](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=23154.)
- 0.01% BAC if [the driver is under the age of 21](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=23136.)
- 0.08% BAC if [none of the above cases apply](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=23152.)

California law permits the blood-alcohol content to be determined through [a breath test, a blood test, or in limited circumstances, urinalysis](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/?1dmy&urile=wcm:path:/dmv_content_en/dmv/pubs/brochures/fast_facts/ffdl35).